# Combining Code Review with Trust Metrics

Tags: version-control, code-reviews

I don't get the chance to partake of it at work. But I love the idea of **code review**. 
Especially of online open source code review like Gerrit Code Review.

I love what **Trust Metrics** have done for forums and collective intelligences sites on the internet like stackexchange, reddit, and wikipedia.

Would it be possible to combine the two and come up with an open source project management system. 
Something that ends up being mostly community driven.

Perhaps a kind of wikipedia of code for a project.
Where submitters become popular/trusted by having lots of patches reviewed favoriably by others, and accepted into the trunk.
And popular/trusted submitters get their patchs accepted faster/easier.

I'm looking for some opinions on the idea, or perhaps pointers to where its been done before, if thats the case.

This might leave the lead maintiner little more to do than:

- wrangle the direction of the project by fast-tracking or vetoing specific patches.
- settling disputes when the CI tests break, or fixing it himself.

Is design by community worse than design by committee?

Comment: If only there was a way to combine Code Review with a Stack-Exchange style trust metric... ( http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your idea very much but i donot think that it will work :-(

community-sites are based on win-win-situations.

- The asker get an answer to an important question.
- the question-reader learns a lot about problems and their solutions.
- The answerer get reputation(-points).

Your idea adds additional winners

- (co-) authors have better open source code
- chances are higher that development of that project goes on.

In order to make it simple for all users
it should have a link to codeversioning system (svn, git, mercurial, ....) so there is no need to repost 
sourcecode that goes out of sync with the current verion.

My current experience form http://codereview.stackexchange.com is that **broad unspecific questions** like

```
 What do you think of this code (followed by a few pages of sourcecode)
```

is not very attractive for

- question-readers because you can not selectivly search for interesting topics.
- for answers because there is a lot of code to read out of context of a complete open source project.

**Narrow specific questions** on http://codereview.stackexchange.com like ´How can i optimize ...´ are attractive 
for ´question-readers´ and ´answerers´ but requires that the 
author has the feeling that something has to change.

Codereviews i partcipated in always were combined with refactoring/pairprogramming. 
Is this possible via internet where the pair is separated in space and time?

And just voting of "do you think it should be refactored this way" does not solve the problem if there is nobody who does the actual job.